# OpenGL pre-multiplying alpha in GLSL gives unexpected result for DDS textures

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the following situation. I work on OpenGL renderer (OpenGL 4.2 so no fixed stuff).I DON"T use hardware blending for the reasons related to all sort of image effects I do in shaders.I have as my input textures of 2 types:

1) PNG 24 with alpha channel.
2)DDS (DXT5) with alpha channel.

In the fragment shader I pre-muliply alpha before output:

Fragment shader:

```
     outputColor=texture(colorMap,interpolateAtSample(uvsOut , gl_SampleID));
      /////// PREMULTIPLY ALPHA //////////
     outputColor.a *= alpha;
     outputColor.rgb *= outputColor.a;
```

PNG based textures work fine:
[image]

But DDS looks like this:
[image]

You can see the halo + black edge.
First thing I thought was the problem with alpha multiplication.But then I changed 
Texture filtering for DDS from GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST and it removed both the halo and black edge.
While this "hack" essentially fixed the problem I still would like to understand why GL_LINEAR causes this sort of issues to DDS compressed textures.

Almost forgot: If I remove pre - multiplication it solves the issue for DDS but creates one for PNG based textures.

UPDATE:
There is another pass which comes after the MSAA resolve and that is blend pass.As I mentioned , I don't do any blend in this case but the output code in the blend shader looks like this:

```
         ///Prevent background bleeding:
         blendTex.rgb/=blendTex.a;
         //base texture is the texture under the current one.
         //This particular technique does "NORMAL" blend-just returns blendTex.
         vec4 blendedRes=blendTechnique( baseTex , blendTex) ;
         outputColor= vec4( blendedRes.rgb * blendTex.a, blendTex.a);
```

Comment: "*I DON"T use hardware blending for the reasons related to all sort of image effects I do in shaders.*" That's going to make it rather difficult to diagnose your problem. What kind of blending *are* you using? Do you have some code?

Comment: I do no blending for this particular example but alpha pre-multiply only.The chunk of the code at the top of the article does just that.Another thing I haven't mentioned -I do MSAA pass before this one.Can it be related?

Comment: "*I do no blending for this particular example but alpha pre-multiply only.*" That's highly unlikely, since I can see partially through the fuzzy side area of the quad. So you *are* doing blending of some form. What blending are you using? Maybe you forgot to turn it off?

Comment: I updated the question.I do have a blending pass as second pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the issue.My code was in fact correct 100%.The problem was in the specific DDS texture I used for tests.It was corrupted.When I tried different DDS (DXT5) it worked fine both with GL_NEAREST and GL_LINEAR filtering.The important detail to remember is that DDS CAN NOT be pre-multiplied  by default,so if one needs it to be ,do it on GPU.